# SSL certificate for Spring boot application with nginx running on the same server

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, ssl, docker-compose, ssl-certificate

I have server that run docker with Nginx container inside which serve react build files inside, this nginx server have an installed and working SSL certificate on port 80 and 443.

On the same machine I have an JRE that run an Spring boot application that running on port 8801.

I have search for some infomation online related to how to create an SSL certificate for spring boot when port 80 and 443 is in use, or what is the best practice to do it simultaneously with the  existance of SSL certificate, And could not find any.

My friend suggest to me that we will use reverse proxy in order to hide: `http://example.com:8801` under `https://example.com:80/api`

What could be the best way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to terminate the SSL on Nginx and offload that load on the application server (spring boot running tomcat, for eg.).

One reason to take SSL all the way to the app server is when the communication medium between those two needs to be kept secure. But if the app server and the web server are within the DMZ, you can just use the first approach and terminate on the web server. There is a lot of optimization that goes into web servers to handle TLS termination.

Refer to [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30403/should-ssl-be-terminated-at-a-load-balancer) for already detailed responses and insights.